How to make webhook work for button payment?
I created a webhook and added it under the sandbox webhook thing. I subscribed it to all events. I tested it with the webhook simulator and it works fine. However, I made a no code button (smart button) and when I purchased it via the paypal sandbox, nothing is sent to my webhook.

Currently the No Code payment buttons do not work with webhooks in any way. The old IPN service can be used.

thanks, I set up ipn and I get a request now however the body of the request is empty?

should be body in application/x-www-form-urlencoded (form post) format, not JSON
